# Grouping by classes

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to see how many times a url is labelled with 1 and how many times it is labelled with 0.
My dataset is

```
    Label   URL
0   0.0 www.nytimes.com
1   0.0 newatlas.com
2   1.0 www.facebook.com
3   1.0 www.facebook.com
4   0.0 issuu.com
... ... ...
3572    0.0 www.businessinsider.com
3573    0.0 finance.yahoo.com
3574    0.0 www.cnbc.com
3575    0.0 www.ndtv.com
3576    0.0 www.baystatehealth.org
```

I tried `df.groupby("URL")["Label"].count()` but it does not return the expected output:

```
    Label   URL           Freq
0   0.0 www.nytimes.com    1
0   1.0 www.nytimes.com    0
1   0.0 newatlas.com       1
1   1.0 newatlas.com       0
2   1.0 www.facebook.com   2
2   0.0 www.facebook.com   0
4   0.0 issuu.com          1
4   1.0 issuu.com          0
... ... ...
```

What field should I consider I the group by to get something like the above df (expected output)?

Comment: Since I need to sort values by descending order, I would need another column, called Frequency. unfortunately all the answers do not show this column and I do not know how to sort the values using Label

Answer (score 1):

You need unique combinations of URL and Label.

```
df.groupby(["URL","Label"]).count()
```

Comment: Thanks Rajith! May I ask you how to sort by descending order based on the count? If I use: `.count().sort_values(by=['Label'], ascending=False)` , it just gives me 1.0 as maximum or highest value (when actually it should be 2 from facebook)

Comment: use reset_index() to reset the indexes.this will make url and label back to df as columns.after that you can use sort_values by Label. `df=df.groupby(["URL","Label"]).count().reset_index()  df.sort_values(by="Label",ascending=False)`

Comment: I tried as you suggested: `.count().reset_index().sort_values(by=['Label'], ascending=False)` but it still gives me 1.0 as maximum value

Comment: there is no error anymore, but the problem I think is in the groupby as I would need to first count how many times a websites has 1.0 or 0.0 value, then selecting those ones which have the maximum value per class (for example facebook with 2.0 for 1.0). I think there should be another column for frequency

Answer (score 1):

Now you can do `value_counts`

```
df.value_counts(["URL","Label"])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer BEN_YO. I got this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Comment: @still_learning this is new for pandas 1.1.0~https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html

Comment: Thanks BEN_YO. However I think the problem is in sorting the values, as I have not a column frequency which counts them and that I can sort

Answer (score 0):

Use agg:

```
df.groupby("URL").agg({'Label',lambda x: x.nunique()})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, Mehdi. I got this error however: AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'Label'